# Reason for publishing error "could not find a part of the path" in VS19 (Errors: MSB3027, MSB3021)?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

There are several questions posted about this, but I tried many of the solutions and it did not fix my issue.

The issue is when I publish my ASP.NET Core 2.2 project, I get this error (formatted for easier readability):

```
Unable to copy file "C:\Users\lfirstname\TFS\dotnet\Project Name\Project Name\Dev\LFirstname\BranchName\Project Name\Website\wwwroot\lib\jquery-validation-unobtrusive\jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"  
 
to  
 
"C:\Users\lfirstname\TFS\dotnet\Project Name\Project Name\Dev\LFirstname\BranchName\Project Name\Website\obj\Release\netcoreapp2.2\win-x64\PubTmp\Out\wwwroot\lib\jquery-validation-unobtrusive\jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js".  
 
Could not find a part of the path  
 
'C:\Users\lfirstname\TFS\dotnet\Project Name\Project Name\Dev\LFirstname\BranchName\Project Name\Website\obj\Release\netcoreapp2.2\win-x64\PubTmp\Out\wwwroot\lib\jquery-validation-unobtrusive\jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js'.
```

In the publish output I get warning MSB3026, and errors MSB3027 and MSB3021.

The only way I managed to go around it is by branching out of the branch I was trying to publish. Then, in the new branch, publishing was successful. However, this is an inconsistent fix because at one point I had to branch out of the original branch again, and I had similar errors when publishing the new one (this time it was picking on some other files in addition to jquery).

I'm wondering why is this happening and why does branching out (sometimes) fix it?

Some of the other things I tried that did not work:

- cleaning and rebuilding project and solution
- restarting VS and the PC
- deleting `obj` and `bin` folders in the solution
- deleting local copy of project (and its parent folders) and getting latest in TFS
- creating a new publish profile

EDIT: When I make a new branch, it publishes successfully and the output is like this

```
Website -> C:\Users\lfirstname\TFS\dotnet\Project Name\Project Name\Dev\LFirstname\BranchName\Project Name\Website\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.2\win-x64\Website.dll
Website -> C:\Users\lfirstname\TFS\dotnet\Project Name\Project Name\Dev\LFirstname\BranchName\Project Name\Website\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.2\win-x64\Website.Views.dll
Website -> C:\Users\lfirstname\TFS\dotnet\Project Name\Project Name\Dev\LFirstname\BranchName\Project Name\Website\obj\Release\netcoreapp2.2\win-x64\PubTmp\Out\
Web App was published successfully file:///C:/Users/lfirstname/TFS/dotnet/Project%20Name/Project%20Name/Dev/LFirstname/BranchName/Project%20Name/Website/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.2/publish/
```

Just wanted to say that I noticed it's the third line that starts failing and giving me errors about about not being able to copy jquery js file.

EDIT 2: I'm encountering this issue yet again. This time I noticed that only one of the publish profile's configuration settings encounters this error. But on my coworkers machine the same code publishes fine with the configuration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With lots of help, I finally know what the problem was. Due to the project's location and certain JS libraries, some of the file paths were over 260 characters (the limit for Windows 10), resulting in failure to publish some files.

The solution is to [make Windows 10 accept file paths over 260 characters](https://www.howtogeek.com/266621/how-to-make-windows-10-accept-file-paths-over-260-characters/).

**A note from the article**:

> Standard warning: Registry Editor is a powerful tool and misusing
> it can render your system unstable or even inoperable.

So, if you're on your work machine and you don't normally use the registry, it's best to ask someone above for help. If you need to tackle this yourself, please do so with extra care.